# It does not take a multi-threaded query

Tags: java, android, httpclient

faced with multi-threading when sending HTTP requests
a feeling that they are still waiting for the completion of each other ..

because the speed of queries is not impressed (compared to C # \ Perl)

For the first time faced with a similar to C #, it turned out that the problem was solved by removing limits on connections

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100;
```

Can someone tell what is wrong in my example?
whether there are such limits in java?

```
 public static String requester(String url, String param, int head, String cook, int ajax) {
    HttpClient client = getHttpsClient(new DefaultHttpClient());
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    String ans = new String();

    if(ajax == 1) {
        httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
        httppost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    }

    httppost.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36");
    if(cook != "") {
        httppost.setHeader("Cookie", cook);
    }

    try {

        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(param);
        se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
        httppost.setEntity(se);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);

        if(head == 1) {
            ans = TextUtils.join("\r\n", response.getAllHeaders());
        }

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        for (String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
            builder.append(line).append("\n");
        }

        ans += builder.toString();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Log.d("ClientProtocolException","Some Wrong 1");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("ClientProtocolException", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }


    return ans;
}
```

....

```
    public void brute(View v)
    {
        flag = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            new TheTask().execute();
        }
    }

   class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            while(true)
            {
               ..........



public static HttpClient getHttpsClient(HttpClient client) {
    try{
        X509TrustManager x509TrustManager = new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                           String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                                           String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            @Override
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
        };

        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        ConnManagerParams.setMaxConnectionsPerRoute(params, new ConnPerRouteBean(100));
        ConnManagerParams.setMaxTotalConnections(params, 10000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSocketBufferSize(params,8192);
        HttpConnectionParams.setTcpNoDelay(params, true);

        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
        ClientConnectionManager clientConnectionManager = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);


        clientConnectionManager.setMaxTotal (1000);
        clientConnectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute (100);

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{x509TrustManager}, null);
        SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = new ExSSLSocketFactory(sslContext);
        sslSocketFactory.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
        //ClientConnectionManager clientConnectionManager = client.getConnectionManager();
        SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = clientConnectionManager.getSchemeRegistry();
        schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("https", sslSocketFactory, 443));
        //return new DefaultHttpClient(clientConnectionManager, client.getParams());
        return new DefaultHttpClient(clientConnectionManager, params);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient' , version: '4.3.6'

Comment: I still have two requests per second

Answer (score 0):

See: See http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/performance.html and http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/threading.html.

I can't tell from your post, but you appear not to be re-using the HttpClient, but you're definitely not giving it a thread safe connection manager. There are other performance considerations you may need, depending on your application (but are detailed in the above links).

Also, from my own personal, anecdotal evidence, HttpClient 4.x is generally faster than HttpClient 3.x (again, it's not clear which you're using).

Comment: Oh.. thx! but i have trouble with "setMaxConnectionsPerRoute"
"Cannot resolve method setDefaultMaxPerRoute(int)"

http://cs14113.vk.me/c623321/v623321053/13dae/VkFLteUXCow.jpg

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

```
ConnPerRoute perRoute = new ConnPerRouteBean(100);
ConnManagerParams.setMaxConnectionsPerRoute(params, perRoute);
ConnManagerParams.setMaxTotalConnections(params, 100);
ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, 15000);
```